# Does GHIDRA have a debugger?

Tags: malware, reverse-engineering, debugging

Does GHIDRA have a debugger attached for dynamic analysis of application?

Comment: Take a look at GDB integration: https://github.com/Comsecuris/gdbghidra

Comment: [ret-sync](https://github.com/bootleg/ret-sync) lets you use any debugger youre comfortable with and send the debugger information (like $sp, registers, etc) over to ghidra so you can look at the de compiled code

Answer (score 12):

**Edit:** As the question is a little unclear there might be a misunderstanding. From my point of view there are 2 possible answers:

1. GHIDRA does not offer a debugger for other binaries currently. (It is a [planned feature](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/24#issuecomment-470676329))
2. GHIDRA has a debug mode to debug GHIDRA itself. This debugger is even 
   accessible from the network, as the exposed port is not only locally bound.

**[Hacker Fantastic on Twitter:](https://twitter.com/hackerfantastic/status/1103087869063704576)**

> Ghidra opens up JDWP in debug mode listening on port 18001, you can
>   use it to execute code remotely ‍♂️.. to fix change line 150 of
>   support/launch.sh from * to 127.0.0.1 https://static.hacker.house/releasez/expl0itz/jdwp-exploit.txt

Comment: I think the questioner meant a debugger for targeting AUTs

Comment: This is not the kind of debugger the question is referring to. The debugger in your answer is to debug Ghidra itself. The question wants to execute and instrument a target application.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I might have gotten the question wrong and updated my response.

Answer (score 5):

From Ghidra 10.0, Ghidra debugger is included in the official release:
https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/Ghidra_10.0_build/Ghidra/Configurations/Public_Release/src/global/docs/ChangeHistory.html

From WikiLeaks' "Vault 7: CIA Hacking Tools Revealed", I see Ghidra has a plugin for interaction with OllyDbg ("the Ghidra Debugger") but this OllyDbg plugin has not been released in the Ghidra public release yet.
https://wikileaks.org/ciav7p1/cms/page_51183656.html

Answer (score 4):

As of December 17th (2020), it has. See the announcement in Twitter
https://twitter.com/NSACyber/status/1339652646513291264
and the debugger branch of Ghidra in GitHub
https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/tree/debugger

Answer (score 2):

Now yes!

From Ghidra 10.0 change history

> New Features
>
> - Debugger. Introduced the Debugger, along with GDB and dbgeng.dll connectors for debugging user-mode applications on Linux and Windows, respectively. The UI includes threads, timeline, modules, memory, registers, watches, etc., for examining and controlling debug targets. See Help -> Contents -> What's New for more details. (GP-986)

[Ghidra 10.0 Change History (June 2021)](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/Ghidra_10.0_build/Ghidra/Configurations/Public_Release/src/global/docs/WhatsNew.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ghidra does not have a debugger to date, but can be synchronized with a debugger (eg., x64dbg), with `[ret-sync][1]`:

> ret-sync stands for Reverse-Engineering Tools SYNChronization. It is a
> set of plugins that help to synchronize a debugging session
> (WinDbg/GDB/LLDB/OllyDbg/OllyDbg2/x64dbg) with a disassembler
> (IDA/Ghidra/Binary Ninja). The underlying idea is simple: take the
> best from both worlds (static and dynamic analysis).

In particular:

> Debuggers and dynamic analysis provide us with:
>
> - local view, with live dynamic context (registers, memory, etc.)
> - built-in specialized features/API (ex: WinDbg's !peb, !drvobj, !address, etc.)
>
> Disassemblers and static analysis provide us with:
>
> - macro view over modules
> - code analysis, signatures, types, etc.
> - fancy graph view
> - decompilation
> - persistent storage of knowledge within IDBs/GPRs
>
> Key features:
>
> - synchronize graph and decompilation views with debugger's state
> - no need to deal with ASLR, addresses are rebased on-the-fly
> - pass data (comment, command output) from debugger to disassembler
> - multiple IDBs/GPRs can be synced at the same time allowing to easily trace through multiple modules
> - disassembler and debugger can be on different hosts / VMs